# how can I save the state when I change the page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created two pageview.One for texts ekonom and comfort the second one is for cars view.When I scroll car pageview ,text is also changed.For payment I have dropdown menu.User firstly selects cash or card payment from dropdown menu then pass to car selection.But after changing car page ,the value of dropdown menu  at state is lost.So user has to select payment type from dropdown again.
[image: here you can see]

For better understanding I share my code with you.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:client_shared/components/light_colored_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vector_icons/flutter_vector_icons.dart';
import 'package:client_shared/components/ridy_sheet_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/messages.dart';
import 'package:ridy/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:ridy/main/enter_coupon_code_sheet_view.dart';
import 'package:ridy/main/reserve_ride_sheet_view.dart';
import 'package:ridy/main/ride_preferences_sheet_view.dart';
import 'package:client_shared/theme/theme.dart';
import 'package:ridy/schema.gql.dart';
import '../graphql/generated/graphql_api.graphql.dart';
import '../main/service_item_view.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';

import 'bloc/main_bloc.dart';

class SelectServiceView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectServiceView({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    required this.onServiceSelect,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final GetFare$Query$CalculateFareDTO data;
  final ServiceSelectCallback onServiceSelect;

  @override
  State<SelectServiceView> createState() => _SelectServiceViewState();
}

class _SelectServiceViewState extends State<SelectServiceView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainBloc = (context.read<MainBloc>().state) as OrderPreview;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.mapGreenBackgroundColor,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
          child: const Text(
            'Burada texmini gedis haqqi olacaq',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        RidySheetView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              OrderPreviewServices(
                serviceCategories: widget.data.services,
                currency: widget.data.currency,
                // requestPaymentType: RequestPaymentType.card,
              ),
              // DefaultTabController(
              //     length: widget.data.services.length,
              //     child: Column(
              //       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              //       children: [

              //       ],
              //     )),
              Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: mainBloc.selectedService == null
                      ? null
                      : () async {
                          widget.onServiceSelect(
                              mainBloc.selectedService.toString(), 0);
                        },
                  child: Text(S.of(context).service_selection_book_now),
                )),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(
                            color: AppColors.mapGreenBackgroundColor)),
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
                        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10))),
                    onPressed: mainBloc.selectedService == null
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                            final dialogResult =
                                await showModalBottomSheet<DateTime>(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const ReserveRideSheetView());
                            if (dialogResult == null) return;
                            final difference = dialogResult
                                .difference(DateTime.now())
                                .inMinutes;
                            widget.onServiceSelect(
                                mainBloc.selectedService!.id, difference);
                          },
                    child: Icon(
                      Ionicons.calendar_outline,
                      color: AppColors.appMainColor,
                      size: 28,
                    ).pOnly(bottom: 4)),
              ]).pOnly(top: 10)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class OrderPreviewServices extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<GetFare$Query$CalculateFareDTO$ServiceCategory> serviceCategories;
  final String currency;

  // final RequestPaymentType? requestPaymentType;
  OrderPreviewServices(
      {required this.serviceCategories,
      required this.currency,
      // this.requestPaymentType,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final PageController _pageController1 = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.3);
  final PageController _pageController2 = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainBloc = context.read<MainBloc>();
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: serviceCategories.length,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                S.of(context).select_ride_type,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
          // TabBar(
          //     dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          //     unselectedLabelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
          //     labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
          //     isScrollable: true,
          //     tabs: serviceCategories
          //         .map((e) => Tab(
          //               height: 28,
          //               child: Padding(
          //                   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          //                       horizontal: 16, vertical: 0),
          //                   child: Text(e.name)),
          //             ))
          //         .toList()),
          const Divider(),

          DropdownButtonFormField<RequestPaymentType>(
              value: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: CustomTheme.primaryColors.shade100,
                labelText: S.of(context).action_select_payment_type,
              ),
              icon: const Icon(Ionicons.chevron_down),
              items: <DropdownMenuItem<RequestPaymentType>>[
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: RequestPaymentType.cash,
                  child: Text(S.of(context).payment_in_cash),
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: RequestPaymentType.card,
                  child: Text(S.of(context).enum_paymentType_card),
                ),
              ],
              onChanged: (RequestPaymentType? value) {
                (mainBloc.state as OrderPreview).requestPaymentType = value;
                print(
                    "odenisin novu =>${(mainBloc.state as OrderPreview).requestPaymentType}");
              }),
          const Divider(),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            child: TabBarView(
              children: serviceCategories.map((l) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: PageView.builder(
                          itemCount: l.services.map((e) {}).toList().length,
                          padEnds: false,
                          controller: _pageController1,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  mainBloc
                                      .add(SelectService(l.services[index]));
                                  _pageController2.animateToPage(index,
                                      duration:
                                          const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                      curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  l.services[index].name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: l.services[index].id ==
                                            (mainBloc.state as OrderPreview)
                                                .selectedService
                                                ?.id
                                        ? FontWeight.bold
                                        : FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: l.services[index].id ==
                                            (mainBloc.state as OrderPreview)
                                                .selectedService
                                                ?.id
                                        ? Colors.black
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.22,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: PageView.builder(
                          onPageChanged: (int index) {
                            mainBloc.add(SelectService(l.services[index]));
                            _pageController2.animateToPage(index,
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                          },
                          //pageSnapping: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ServiceItemView(
                                isSelected: l.services[index].id ==
                                    (mainBloc.state as OrderPreview)
                                        .selectedService
                                        ?.id,
                                service: l.services[index],
                                currency: currency,
                                index: index,
                                pgController: _pageController2);
                          },
                          itemCount: l.services.map((e) {}).toList().length,
                          padEnds: false,
                          controller: _pageController2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          // SizedBox(
          //   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3,
          //   child: TabBarView(
          //     children: serviceCategories.map((l) {
          //       return  SizedBox(
          //         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.25,
          //         child: Column(children: [
          //           ScrollExtensio
          //         ],),
          //       ) /* ListView(
          //         padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          //         children: e.services
          //             .map((e) => ServiceItemView(
          //                   service: e,
          //                   isSelected: e.id ==
          //                       (mainBloc.state as OrderPreview)
          //                           .selectedService
          //                           ?.id,
          //                   currency: currency,
          //                 ))
          //             .toList(),
          //       )*/;
          //     }).toList(),
          //   ),
          // ),
          const Divider(),
          Row(
            children: [
              BlocBuilder<MainBloc, MainBlocState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is! OrderPreview ||
                      state.selectedService == null ||
                      state.selectedService!.options.isEmpty) {
                    return const SizedBox();
                  }
                  return LightColoredButton(
                      icon: Ionicons.options,
                      text: S.of(context).action_ride_preferences,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final dialogResult = await showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            isScrollControlled: true,
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
                            builder: (context) {
                              return RidePreferencesSheetView(
                                  state.selectedService!,
                                  state.selectedOptions);
                            });
                        if (dialogResult != null) {
                          final points = state.points;
                          context.read<MainBloc>().add(ShowPreview(
                                points: points,
                                selectedOptions: dialogResult,
                                couponCode: state.couponCode,
                              ));
                        }
                      });
                },
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              LightColoredButton(
                  icon: Ionicons.pricetag,
                  text: S.of(context).action_coupon_code,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final bloc = context.read<MainBloc>();
                    (bloc.state as OrderPreview);
                    final code = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
                        context: context,
                        isScrollControlled: true,
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const EnterCouponCodeSheetView();
                        });
                    if (code.isEmptyOrNull) return;

                    bloc.add(ShowPreview(
                        points: (bloc.state as OrderPreview).points,
                        selectedOptions:
                            (bloc.state as OrderPreview).selectedOptions,
                        couponCode: code));
                  })
            ],
          ).pSymmetric(v: 4)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef ServiceSelectCallback = void Function(
  String serviceId,
  int intervalMinutes,
);
```

I tried to apply keys for each pageviewBuilder even PageStorageKey,but it did not help.
How can I save the state of screen?

Answer (score 0):

**AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** is used to maintained the state in stateful widgets.

**Example:**

```
class KeepAliveWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const KeepAliveWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<KeepAliveWidget> createState() => _KeepAliveWidgetState();
}

class _KeepAliveWidgetState extends State<KeepAliveWidget>  with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return const Placeholder();
  }
  
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir I tried but it did not help as well...